# How to get the first available row in simultaneous connections?

Tags: php, mysql

I assign the first available row to each coming user as

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE status IS NULL ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
fetched id is xxx
UPDATE table1 SET status='taken' WHERE id=xxx
```

How can I make sure that not a second user retrieve the same id before it is `UPDATE`d as taken?

NOTE: It has nothing to do with `INSERT`. The table is already there. Users should take the first available row. `UPDATE` is just to keep track of taken rows.

Comment: If id is **auto_incremented** and is the **primary key**, you shouldn't have to care about this.

Comment: @Maincore unless another user is created, before updating the first one.

Comment: Yes. Just use auto_increment to take care of this for you

Comment: @IvankaTodorova No. It's irrelevant.

Comment: Why not use sub query as `UPDATE table1 SET status='taken' WHERE id =(SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1)`

Comment: What is the structure of your schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html):

```
start transaction;
SELECT @A:=id FROM table1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
UPDATE table1 SET status='taken' WHERE id=@A
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Transactionless version:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE status != 'taken' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
fetched id is xxx
UPDATE table1 SET status='taken' WHERE id=xxx AND status != 'taken'
check number of affected rows
```

Comment: What if `affected_rows=0`? repeating the process again and again?

Comment: Up to you really. What you gonna do when transaction fails (referring to @ivanka-todorova 's answer)?